# Import SQL using terminal on a Mac

Tags: mysql, import, terminal

I'm learning SQL - working my way through a book.
I have mysql client set up and running. I have added and created databases and tables manually, no more than about ten records and fields.
I'm now working through a chapter all about selecting records based on criteria. 
I would therefore like to import a larger database to play around with. I have downloaded the "world.sql" file from mysql.com. This file contains all of the worlds cities and associated data such as population - a good table to play around with.
I have downloaded the file to my desktop but I do not know how to actually add to a database in order to use.
I created a new database in the terminal called "world". I now need to import the sql file to this database but do not know how to?
What commands am I looking for here?

Answer (score 1):

Call `mysql` from the shell and pipe the `world.sql` file to it:

```
$ mysql -uYOURUSER -pYOURPASSWORD < world.sql
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm almost there except do I need to spell out the full path to the desktop after the "<"? I've tried
 -u myname@localhost </user/myname/world.sql
Thats not working... am I close? (I currently do not have a password as I've just set up)

Comment: Hm. But the SQL file came from the mysql.com site. Thanks all the same

Comment: This one? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html Note that it is packed, you have to extract it first (`gunzip world.sql.gz` or `unzip world.sql.zip`, depending on the format you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p {db_name} < {path_to_file/file.sql}
```

OR

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

enter password then

```
use db_name
```

then

```
source path_to_file/file.sql
```

if you get foreign key error than first use following command before import

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Then

```
source path_to_file/file.sql
```